# Нет Python.h в C/С++ на Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, c, include

Пытаюсь интегрировать питон в Си, но столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу запустить программу из-за того, что нет нужной мне библиотеки в Си, а как ее скачать без понятия (поиски в интернете не увенчались успехом).

И вот вопрос: как установить данную библиотеку или ее замены для Си?

Весь интернет просмотрел, но ничего не нашел для винды

Comment: Python.h лежит в одной из папок внутри папки Python, а именно в папке include. Также для сборки вам нужны будут статические библиотеки (.lib), они лежат в папке libs.

Comment: @insolor Я нашел их. Как тогда их подключить к С в Visual Studio?

Comment: Без понятия, где-то в свойствах проекта скорее всего. Я собирал только через командную строку с помощью mingw